# How do I disable Facebook "infinite scroll"?

Tags: facebook, browser-addons

It's really annoying the way Facebook constantly loads extra items when I scroll down.

Either show me all unseen content right away, or let me click the button to load more - either would be fine.

Is there a way to prevent the annoying scrolling behaviour?

(via Firefox plugin, preferably. Chrome or Opera plugin if necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from a user script (which most likely would be what be needed to interrupt the scroll), it takes me two *quick* scrolls to get to the bottom.

This could also be accomplished with End the key (on Mac Cmd and <kbd>↓</kbd> )
It is not a nice solution if you are not good quick scrolls, but it does the job for me.

So far all the user-scripts I have seen have tried to enhance this feature rather than disable it (e.g. [FFixer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/8861)). If you could work backwards from that script maybe you will figure out how to stop it.

It seems the call goes to `morestories.php` via Ajax in the following function

`function UIIntentionalStream` and the scroll loader if you can find a user script that handles then hopefully that can push you in the right direction.

Comment: Saying "just scroll down" is not an answer to "how can I block the need to scroll down".  
     
It also doesn't solve anything - my connection is slow/inconsistent enough that I sometimes need do this several times in order to reach the end of loading, which doesn't stop the experience being frustrating!

Comment: @Peter I am not saying just scroll down. It is a **quick** scroll (maybe your pc does not have this) I have tried it using both a two finger scroll to the bottom (x2) and Mac + ↓ (x2). If you have a PC. Try it with the End Key. The results are consistent. A slow internet connection is irrelevant.

Comment: Uh... is "quick scroll" some magic terminology? I know what the End key does.  
  
//  
  
I found this: http://mactips.info/2005/03/quick-scroll but it doesn't seem to be what you're referring to?  
  
//  
  
Pressing End once takes me to the bottom (and FB starts loading more).  
Pressing End twice - whether quickly or slowly - does not stop it loading.  
Right now, it takes *five* End presses until FB gives up loading.

Answer (score 1):

Social Fixer did the trick for me

http://socialfixer.com/

> Social fixer will let facebook to automatically load only 5 times, then you will have to click "More stories". From their website: "Posts will be auto-loaded as you scroll down, as it is by default on Facebook. However, Social Fixer stops the auto-loading after 5 page loads, to prevent their code from going into an eternal loop and loading hundreds of pages worth of posts. This is a necessary trade-off, and to continue loading more you can just click ‘More Stories’.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why this was the right tool for the job?  Thanks.

Comment: Social fixer will let facebook to automatically load only 5 times, then you will have to click "More stories". From their website: "Posts will be auto-loaded as you scroll down, as it is by default on Facebook. However, Social Fixer stops the auto-loading after 5 page loads, to prevent their code from going into an eternal loop and loading hundreds of pages worth of posts. This is a necessary trade-off, and to continue loading more you can just click ‘More Stories’. " http://socialfixer.com/blog/category/releasenotes/